# Is there a way to load string html with webView.loadDataWithBaseURL() in an Ionic app?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to load a html string inside webview with loadDataWithBaseURL() with baseurl as "http:/localhost"in a cordova plugin. With this I am getting an error  " http://localhost/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". What mistake I am doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the location of Favicon.ico, 
   if your Favicon.ico is not under folder structure of app then above error may throw.
2. Check the URL you are hitting inside app for connecting localhost and mention port over which you are talking to the server.